# Binding Event to View Model, Rotation of Image

Tags: xaml, mvvm

I want to have a Rotation of an Image, but I don't want to Code the Events inside the Codebehind but in the View Model.
By now everything works fine, BUT the code is in the CodeBehind...
(It's based on [this](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/03/28/Creating-touch-based-rotation-in-Windows-8-XAML-Store-apps.aspx) tutorial)

I tried

XAML:

```
 [...]
 ManipulationDelta="{Binding RotateManipulationDelta}"
 [...]
 <RotateTransform x:Name="{Binding RotateTransform}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
private void RotateManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Alternatively, use Triangle Cosines Law.
        // It uses just one trigonometric function (Acos), but you first need to calculate the lengths of all sides.

        var x = this.RotateTransform.CenterX - e.Position.X;
        var y = this.RotateTransform.CenterY - e.Position.Y;

        double a1 = Math.Atan(y / x);
        double a2 = Math.Atan((e.Delta.Translation.Y - y) / (x - e.Delta.Translation.X));

        this.RotateTransform.Angle += a1 - a2;
    }
```

But C# obviously doesn't know "RotateTransform" or the Method itself.
Is there a possibility to do so? I have no clue.
And please try to explain it as simple as possible. I just started with Windows Apps and XAML. :D

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Ideally you might make it as a UserControl and put some code behind is not a bad idea in UserControl. This piece of code is totally related to UI itself so why do you want it in ViewModel?

Comment: Well, I need to get the RotateTransform.Angle as a value inside the View Model to do more things with it. 
And my idea was: if the whole animation is in the ViewModel it may helps...
But maybe it wasn't the best idea :)

But do I have acces to Image.RotateTransform.Angle in the View Model?

Comment: If you need some data transferring between View and ViewModel, such as Angle in your case, you can define a dependency property inside your UserControl and let ViewModel's property binds to it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at something like this [Storyboarded animations for visual states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj819808.aspx) or this [XAML animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350512/wpf-xaml-animation-newbie).

I don't get why you want to do something like this... Can you give us more infos ? It will be much more easy to do it in C# than in XAML. The point of the code behind is to do that stuff.